# IndexedDB: executing function with method add several times - no new DB-entry

Tags: javascript, sapui5, indexeddb

I have created a function to store data in indexed db:

```
    var request = window.indexedDB.open("mynewDB", 1);

    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        var db = event.target.result;
        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("toDoList", {keyPath: 'key', autoIncrement: true});  
        var txn = event.target.transaction;
        var addRequest = txn.objectStore("toDoList").add({value: storagedata});   
      }
```

(FYI: the storagedata is filled with a base64 string)

If i am executing this function via button the content of variable storagedata is in the IndexedDB. But if i want to press the button again to store another value into the IndexedDB, nothing happens.

In addition to that if i am executing the function the second time the function jumps at line `request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {` in to the timeout of file "intervalTrigger-dbg.js" to code `clearTimeout(this._delayedCallId);`

What i did to solve the problem: debugging in browser and reading a lot of documentations about indexeddb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem on my own.
For everyone who want to know how it works:

```
     var request = window.indexedDB.open("yourDB-1", 1);
     var db;
     var transaction;
     var store;

    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
       var db = event.target.result;
       var transaction = event.target.transaction;
       var store = db.createObjectStore("yourDB", {keyPath: 'key', autoIncrement: true});
       }

    request.onerror = function (event) {
      console.log("Here is a error: " + event.target.errorCode);
    }

    request.onsuccess = function (event) {
      db = request.result;
      transaction = db.transaction("yourDB", "readwrite");
      store = transaction.objectStore("yourDB");

      db.onerror = function(event){
        console.log("ERROR" + event.target.errorCode);
      }

      store.put({value: storagedata});

      transaction.complete = function() {
        db.close();
      }
    }
```